# Im not quite sure how to configure db2drivers in liberty profile

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, ear

I have to deploy an EAR application in Liberty profile running on a Linux machine. My application has to access the data from a DB2 database. I’m not quite sure how to configure db2drivers in liberty profile.
The jars I have to include are db2jcc4.jar db2jcc_license_cu.jar.

Comment: Did you look at : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example data source configuration for DB2 in Liberty, which can be put in server.xml,

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature>
  <feature>jndi-1.0</feature> <!-- needed for JNDI lookups of data source -->
  ... other features
</featureManager>

<dataSource id="myDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/MyDataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="db2jars"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="TESTDB" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50000" user="dbuser1" password="dbpwd1"/>
</dataSource>

<library id="db2jars">
    <fileset dir="C:/DB2/java" includes="db2jcc4.jar db2jcc_license_cu.jar"/>
</library>
```

Additional examples can be found in [this knowledge center doc.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html)